# error using inheritance with arraylist in JAVA

Tags: java

I have a homework which is as following

I need to create on Interface

ant then I have to use this interface to create two abstract classes

then I have to use these two abstract classes to create 4 complete classes.

The problem is at the end I need to create a class that have an arraylist of the type of the interface so any kind of classes I created can be added to that list

now after I did that

I can only use the methods declared in the first interface.

So I cant use any method from the other classes I created.

Here is my codes so You can check it

Interface:

```
public interface Security {
    //Methods
    public void Description();
}
```

Abstract classes

```
public abstract class DeviceSecurity implements Security {

    //Variables

    boolean Status;

    //Methods

    abstract public void reset();

    public boolean getStatus(){
        return Status;
    }


}


public abstract class LiveSecurity implements Security {

    //Methods

    abstract public void Attack();
    abstract public void stopAttack();
    abstract public void Shout(String message);

}
```

Concrete classes:

```
    import java.util.Arrays;


public class Cypher extends DeviceSecurity {

    //Variables

    int[] password = new int[4];

    //Constructor

    public Cypher(int[] password){

        Status = false;
        this.password = password;

    }

    //Methods

    public boolean Open(int[] password){

        if( Check(password) ){
            Status = true;
            return true;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Wrong Password");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean Change(int[] password , int[] newpassword){

        if( Check(password) && !Status && newpassword.length == 4){
            this.password = newpassword;
            return true;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Wrong Password");
            return false;
        }

    }

    public boolean Close(){
        if(Status){
            Status = false;
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

    }

    public boolean Check(int[] password){

        if(Arrays.equals(this.password, password)){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void reset(){
            this.password = null;
    }

    public void Description(){
        System.out.println("this is a " + this.getClass().getName());
    }

}


public class Guard extends LiveSecurity {

    //Variables

    int experience;
    int age;
    String name;
    char gender;
    String arm;

    //Constructor

    public Guard(int experience , int age , String name , char gender , String arm){
        this.experience = experience;
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.arm = arm;
    }

    //Methods

    public void Watch(){
        System.out.println("Looking Out");
    }

    public void getRest(int hour , int minute){
    if( hour <=23 && minute <=59){
        System.out.println("Resting at :" + hour + ":" + minute);
        }
    }

    public void Attack(){
        System.out.println("Attacking");
    }

    public void stopAttack(){
        System.out.println("Stop Attack");
    }

    public void Shout(String message){
        System.out.println(message);
    };

    public void Description(){

        System.out.println("This is a " + this.getClass().getName() + "; experience , age , name , gender and arm are given respectively: " + experience +", "+age + ", "+ gender + ", " + arm);
    }


}
```

and here is my final class that have the Arraylist in it

```
    import java.util.*;

public class MyHomeSecurity {

    //Defining ArrayList for Security Objects

    ArrayList<Security> allSecurity = new ArrayList<Security>();

    //Constructor unlimited parameters

    public MyHomeSecurity(Security... args) {
        for (Security arg : args) {
              addSecurity(arg);
             }

    }

    //Methods

    public void addSecurity(Security security){
        allSecurity.add(security);
    }

    public void removeSecurity(Security security){
        allSecurity.remove(security);
    }

    public void information(){
        int size = allSecurity.size();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++){
            allSecurity.get(i).Description();
        }
    }

}


I tested my work by writing this class


public class testClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = {1,4,0,2};
        int[] y = {1,4,0,3};

        Cypher Cypher = new Cypher(x);
        Camera Camera = new Camera(true);
        Dog Dog = new Dog("Buldog");
        Guard Guard = new Guard(7 , 35 , "Halit" , 'm' , "Hand Gun");


        MyHomeSecurity home = new MyHomeSecurity( Cypher , Camera , Dog , Guard);
        home.information();

        home.allSecurity.get(0).Check(y); //Here I get error because method Check() is not defined in interface


    }

}
```

any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: Well, if you **declare** an object to be of Security type, then the compiler knows only about the methods which are implemented by this particular interface. If you know to which class exactly this object belongs, you can perform a specific cast, and then use method implemented by that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
home.allSecurity.get(0).Check(y);
```

Either add `Check()` method to the Security interface, or change the type of `allSecurity` to some sub-interface of `Security` or a class implementing `Security` that contain the `Check` method.

Without doing one of these things, the compiler can't know if `home.allSecurity.get(0)` will always return an instance of a class that contains the `Check` method.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach (if it makes sense) is to abstract the class-specific calls into high-level operations that are shared by all classes and declare abstract action methods in the `Security` interface. But often, unfortunately, that doesn't make sense. It risks forcing the interface to know about the internals of each subclass.

Another possibility is to do run-time type checking (using `instanceof`) as you iterate over your list of `Security` objects. But that's pretty ugly.

The main problem is that you want to do a form of [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) (calling different methods based on the run-time type of each `Security` object in the list) and Java does not support that directly. However, you can roll your own using the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). This involves a bit of work, but is quite robust provided the set of concrete classes doesn't change too often. It involves declaring an interface for a "visitor". In your case, it might be:

```
public interface SecurityVisitor {
    void visit(Cypher cypher);
    void visit(Guard guard);
    void visit(Camera camera);
    void visit(Dog dog);
}
```

Then extend your base `Security` interface with a single method:

```
void acceptVisitor(SecurityVisitor);
```

and implement the method in each concrete class. The implementation is very simple:

```
public class Cypher {
    ...
    public void acceptVisitor(SecurityVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}
```

Then you can implement visitors to do different things. For instance, you might have a "status check" visitor that checks on the status of each `Security` object, but does it differently (calls different methods) for each concrete class. You can have a visitor that implements a no-op for every visit except for `Dog` (to make sure the dog is fed, for instance).

The main downside is that each visitor needs to handle visits to all the concrete types (which is why this pattern isn't so wonderful if the set of concrete types changes frequently). Also,